combinatorial analysis (poker hands)
If it is assumed that all 5) poker hands are equally likely, what is the probability of being dealt :
two pairs? (This occurs when the cards have denominations a, a, b, b, c, where a, b, and c are all distinct.)
my answer was (13c1)(4c2)(12c1)(4c2)(11c1)(4c1) / (52c5)
however this was wrong and supposedly the answer was (13c1)(4c2)(4c2)(11c1)(4c1) / (52c5)
I cannot intuitively understand why my solution was incorrect because I feel like they are both explaining the same thing however yield different solutions.

your answer appears to be correct.  the "supposed" answer doesn't try to pick the rank of the second pair.

Neither of those is correct.    Yours is off by a factor of $2$ since you count $AABBC$ and $BBAAC$ as if they were distinct.  The second is wrong since the first term ought to be $\binom {13}{2}$ not $\binom {13}1$ as you are choosing two ranks, not one.  (Note:  I suspect that you simply mistyped the second one, or else your source had a typo).

Note that the duplicate coincides with your question, except that it has the correct factor of $\binom {13}2$ in the official method.
